# Run python files in Cmder/ConEmu vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conemu, cmder

By default, vs code runs the python file in the 'python' terminal it creates, but I want this to run in **external terminal** of Cmder/ConEmu. How can I do it?

Comment: is cmder/ConEmu a separate package? Regadless, this is probably one to raise with the VS people (does it have a forum?)  It's likely too specific a request here.

Comment: Cmder and ConEmu are cmd emulators

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the cmder shell in VSCode. You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows).

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "cmder": {
      "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",  //point to the cmd.exe location
      "args": ["/K", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.cmd"]  //point to vscode_init.cmd which under the installation location of the cmder
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "cmder"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I wanted. I want the file to run in an external cmder window, not an integrated one. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @Groks_45 Could you have a look at the update of this answer? thanks.

Comment: I have already tried to do this. With these settings, cmder is simply launched, but the code does not execute itself.

Comment: @Groks_45 Sorry for that, it does really not work, it seems like you only can take the method which mentioned in this answer.